# Creating Code-Activity unit test while using GetExtension

Tags: unit-testing, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, mstest

How do I create unit test with context based on integration component?

I have identified problem as the Extension is trying to resolve implementation and returning error message:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

My class:

```
 public sealed class GetListOfServiceIdsToProcess
{
   public InOutArgument<IArguments> Arguments { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {

        // I am recieving my error exception here
        context.GetExtension<lib.Extension.MyExtenstion>();

        var targetIds= (List<int>)Settings.Get("targetIds");

        var wfa = this.Arguments.Get(context);
        wfa.ListTargetIds = targetIds;

        Arguments.Set(context, wfa);            
    }
}
```

My Test so far:

I have problem with implementation of the test as far i could get it:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///A test for Execute
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    public void ExecuteTest()
    {
        // create Isettings mock to return collection of service ids

        var expected = new List<int>() { 30, 20 };

        var wfaInput = new TestWorkFlow();

        var serviceIdList = new GetListOfServiceIdsToProcess();
        var wfParam = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        wfParam.Add("WorkFlowArguments", wfaInput);

        var results = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(serviceIdList, wfParam);
        var wfaResult = (IWorkFlowArguments)results["WorkFlowArguments"];

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, wfaResult.ListOfServiceIdsToProcess);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run through multiple options and the problem what I have is MS Workflow.
I have extracted all logic away from workflow code activity into separate class and this class has been put under tests.

This is the best I could do for this. As I have base classes, that are injected, but I could not easily implement what I needed.

Thank you all for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the static WorkflowInvoker.Invoke() new up a WorkflowInvoker instance and add a mock, or whatever is needed for your test, lib.Extension.MyExtenstion to the Extensions collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestMethod]
public void ExecuteTest()
{
    // ...

    var invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(activityToTest); 

    // This way your extension will be available during execution
    invoker.Extensions.Add(new MyExtension());

    var results = invoker.Invoke(inputArgs);

    // ....

}
```